# apache configuration for simple python run in kali linux through php script

Tags: php

**The Problem:**

How to do apache configuration for simple python program run in kali linux through php script.

I tried for this but it shows blank window.
php script:

```
<?php
    $co = escapeshellcmd('/root/Desktop/python1.py');
    $op = shell_exec($co);
    echo $op;
?>
```

in var_dump it shows NULL.
Help ME..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want point to a shell program

```
<?php
$co = escapeshellcmd('/bin/sh /root/Desktop/python1.py');
$op = shell_exec($co);
echo $op;
?>
```

Or use python it self

```
$co = escapeshellcmd('/usr/bin/python /root/Desktop/python1.py');
```

**PS**

When you know the command, the `escapeshell` is redundant, you can use `shell_exec` directly

```
<?php

$op = shell_exec('/bin/bash /root/Desktop/python1.py');
echo $op;
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You sir but  it not works.again same problem is occure

Comment: Post your problem, please, what is it?

Comment: Sir it's again shows blank screen and in var_dump it shows NULL.

Comment: There are several things you must to check: the existence of such files as `python1.py`, second by which user you run you script, if you run `php` by other user than `root`, you may have the permission right problem

Comment: Yes sir "python1.py" is exist and sir i am running this program under root.there is no other user exist in my pc.

Comment: you can check my scripts on the picture, see what happens

Comment: Now Sir it  shows error in python program when we call from php script,but when we run python program from python then its works so dont know why this will happen.

Comment: What is the error, check  `env`, maybe `which python` give different result in the cases, edit your post and add the error